# Azure Table Storage Performance

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-table-storage

How fast should I be expecting the performance of Azure Storage to be? I'm seeing ~100ms on basic operations like getEntity, updateEntity, etc.

This guy seems to be getting 4ms which makes it look like something is really wrong here!

http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/12/working-with-154-million-records-on.html

I'm using the azure-table-node npm plugin.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-table-node

A simple getEntity call is taking ~90ms:

```
exports.get = function(table, pk, rk, callback) {
    var start = process.hrtime();

    client().getEntity(table, pk, rk, function(err, entity) {
        console.log(prettyhr(process.hrtime(start)));
    ...
```

The azure-storage module appears to be even slower:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/azure-storage

```
var start = process.hrtime();

azureClient.retrieveEntity(table, pk, rk, function(err, entity) {
    console.log('retrieveEntity',prettyhr(process.hrtime(start)));
...
```

`retrieveEntity 174 ms`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it really depends from where you are accessing the Azure Storage. 
Are you trying to access the storage from the same DataCenter or just from somewhere on the Internet?

If your code is not running in the same DataCenter then it's just a matter of network latency to perform an HttpRequest to DataCenter where you have your storage running. So this can vary a lot, depending from where you're trying to access the DC and in which region your DC is located. (to make an idea you can check the latency from your pc for example to all Azure DCs Storage here: http://azurespeedtest.azurewebsites.net/

If you're code is running in the same DC, everything should be pretty fast for simple operations such as the ones you are trying out, probably just a few miliseconds.

Comment: good answer. thanks! I ran a website in azure and looked at the console in visual studio live and it looks like the server response time from node.js was as low as 15ms.